# Do C13 male/female cables exist? Or do I even need them?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-management, wiring

I am hoping to plug a few computers into [this HP PDU soon.](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=1i5DGusnJEJUaH7jMfGgPeZz_qV3S6olVRp0N5Y3UHvpYYhl8zU8gVyki9taJ&hl=en)

I have aftermarket power supplies, all of which take [c13 female connections apparently.](https://superuser.com/questions/280624/what-sized-cables-are-most-commonly-used-to-connect-to-psus)

The PDU (from what I gather in the pdf) has 8 * c13 outlets, and 2 * c19 outlets.

On eBay, almost every c13 cable for sale looks like this: [c13 male to c14 female.](http://cgi.ebay.ca/POWER-CABLE-EXTENSION-0-5m-MALE-FEMALE-C13-C14-10Amp-/200606678762?pt=UK_Computing_CablesConnectors_RL&hash=item2eb516feea)

Was the other superuser.com answer (point 2) incorrect? Is it actually a c14 female plug that attaches to most PSUs? Or do I need to find some extremely rare c13-c13 male/female cord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older PSUs also supplied monitors with power and those used a  the male to female connector that connected to the monitor, which used the same 'kettle cord' c13 plug that you used. From what i understand c13 and 14 are male and female of the same size, not different plug form factors - your standard cheap c13-14 cable should work.

There is no such thing as a male c14 or female c13.

Comment: Yeah, I was totally wrong there. The match to a C13 connector is a C14 connector. So an "IEC extension cable" like I mentioned is actually C13->C14.

Comment: yup. and is fairly standard. I'm guessing looking at it that your standard extention cable SHOULD do the trick for connecting from the computer (male end at computer, female end at cable) to the PDU (female end at PDU, male end at cable)

Answer (score 1):

Odd numbers indicate female sockets. Even numbers indicate male sockets. Journeyman Geek is woefully incorrect. C13s are never male and C14s are never female.

http://www.stayonline.com/iec-c13-to-c14-splitter-cables.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As noted already you need a C14-C13 cable (since the number gives the sex).

Such cables are widely available, a search for "IEC C14 C13" (without quotes) will find lots of suppliers for everything from domestic to data centre usage targetted.

Lots of variations available like Y cables allowing one output to power two devices (just watch current loading).